# multicol interline space problems

Tags: multicol

I'm trying to create a template for exam forms, where you have a limited space and usually you want to fir as many formulas as you can. 
So I'm using multicol package for dividing by three the usual space. But I find problems with the interline space in different colums:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}       %Múltiples columnas
\usepackage[top=0.8cm,bottom=0.8cm,left=0.8cm,right=0.8cm,columnsep=14pt]{geometry}  %Ajuste fácil de dimensiones

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\newcommand{\f}[2]{\textbullet \ \ #1 \\
\vspace{0mm}
$#2$ \\}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\f{Schrodinger Equation}{$a = x^2$}
\f{H definition}{$H = a \cdot b$}

\vfill

\centering{.}
\columnbreak

\f{Lorem impsum}{$v_e = 0$}


\vfill   %No quitar esto. Modula la altura de las columnas

.
\columnbreak
\textbf{Something} \\
\f{n values}{$n = 1,2,...,\infty$}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image: Problem in red]

Where you can see that the space bewteen lines changes from the first to the other columns. How can I make that red spaces like the green one?

Thanks a lot, sorry because of my bad english...

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, also what is the intention of `\vspace{0pt}`, why add a zero space? `\centering{.}` sets up centering for the rest of the document, was that intended? (It does not take an argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not ignore warnings such as

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--20
```

Which is TeX warning you of bad (maximally bad) spacing in the document.

I also removed one set of `$` your equations were set in display math, as surrounded by `$$...$$` but very strangely marked up with the outer `$` being supplied by the `\f` command and the inner `$` being in the argument.

If you do want math displays just replace `$...$` in each argument by `[...`]`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}       %Múltiples columnas
\usepackage[top=0.8cm,bottom=0.8cm,left=0.8cm,right=0.8cm,columnsep=14pt]{geometry}  %Ajuste fácil de dimensiones

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\newcommand{\f}[2]{\par\textbullet\quad #1\par
#2\par
\medskip}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\f{Schrodinger Equation}{$a = x^2$}
\f{H definition}{$H = a \cdot b$}

\vfill

\mbox{}%???\centering{.}
\columnbreak

\f{Lorem impsum}{$v_e = 0$}


\vfill   %No quitar esto. Modula la altura de las columnas

.
\columnbreak
\textbf{Something}
\f{n values}{$n = 1,2,...,\infty$}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```